# AJAX callback inside sucess function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, return

I'm trying to return a City from lat/long using a callback from AJAX, but the return is *undefined* although the AJAX is calling the callback with correct value (city).

I've been reading [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) but i am tryng to figure out why the City is still being returned and written as *undefined*.

Here's the whole code:

```
function getLocation(id) {
    x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerText = GetCity(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, returnCity);
        });
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function returnCity(result) {
    return result;
}

function GetCity(lat, long, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&sensor=false",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var city;
            $.each(data['results'], function (i, val) {
                $.each(val['address_components'], function (i, val) {
                    if (val['types'] == "locality,political") {
                        if (val['long_name'] != "") {
                            city = val['long_name'];
                        } else {
                            city = "N/A";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            callback(city);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`GetCity` doesn't return a value, that's why it's always coming back as `undefined`. Asynchronous programming takes time to get the trick of, but in general you usually don't usually use the returns from functions, you're usually passing around callbacks. The tricky bit for what you're trying to do is that you need to keep your element in proper scope so that you can set the inner text in the *callback*. The code below gives you an example using an anonymous function instead of a named function callback.

```
function getLocation(id) {
    x = document.getElementById(id);
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function showPosition(position) {
            GetCity(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, function(result) {
                x.innerText = result;
            });
        });
    } else {
        this.innerHTML = "Geolocation not supported by browser.";
    }
}

function GetCity(lat, long, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + lat + "," + long + "&sensor=false",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            var city;
            $.each(data['results'], function (i, val) {
                $.each(val['address_components'], function (i, val) {
                    if (val['types'] == "locality,political") {
                        if (val['long_name'] != "") {
                            city = val['long_name'];
                        }
                        else {
                            city = "N/A";
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
            callback(city);
        },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
}
```

Comment: i've edited quite a bit, so make sure you get the latest ;)

Comment: With your edited answer you might want to remove the 'id' parameter on GetCity()? It's looking good